# Are there keyboard shortcuts to move paragraphs up or down while editing text?

Tags: keyboard, textedit

Microsoft Word on Windows has this really handy feature where you can move the current paragraph up or down.  I think you type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>, though I don't have a Windows PC in front of me and I can't test that.  The shortcut is far easier than selecting the paragraph, cutting it, moving to the start of the previous (or end of the next) paragraph, then pasting it.

Answer (score 2):

I had to disable two default shortcuts in the keyboard control panel (within System Preferences), that were designated for "Mission Control" and "Application Windows". They were getting in the way of me using this shortcut on Mac Word. Once that is disabled, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>option/alt</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd> arrow.

Answer (score 1):

#### Mac Word

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> both work in the Mac version of Microsoft Word.

#### Text Edit

In Textedit the following should move the paragraph up

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>
3. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
5. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

#### Other options

If you are seriously interested in text editing power, then you might like to check out [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/). In Vim you you could use a command like `dip{p` (i.e., delete in paragraph, navigate up a paragraph, and paste).

Comment: I like the idea of recommending `vi` to somebody currently using MS Word :-)